# refactoring problem with one of my classes

Tags: android, refactoring, android-manifest

i wrote a program and i named my `class StatusListActivity` which `extend Activity`  and is the launcher and main class. I tried refactoring it by  changing the name to something else and whenever i tried to run the application, it closes please do you have an idea of what the problem was.

Comment: Example code would be very handy to give a good diagnosis. The question is rather vauge without it.

Comment: you also can provide some screenshots from DDMS with some error messages

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are developing for Android? In that case, you might have changed the default launcher activity, which you have to reset in the deployment options of your project.

Also, you have to be aware, that by simply renaming a function, you have not changed any references on the code itself. For that, you have to use a proper refactoring-function as e.g. provided by Eclipse in the "Refactor"-Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the name of the Activity class in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

`<activity android:name="activityNewName">`

**EDIT**
Also if activity located in `com.example.myproject.activities.MyActivity`
and in manifest file `<manifest package="com.example.myproject" ...>`
than in manifest must be `<activity android:name=".activities.MyActivity">`

this also true for all other classes that must be in **AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: maybe you also changed package name in your project or moved this class into another package ?

Comment: @Seyi Arigbabowo that`s good, now just mark my answer as best =)